# How to solve RecursionError without sys.setrecursionlimit() in python

Tags: python, recursionerror

I have implemented recursive functions that work on big database and it raises

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

To solve it I added `sys.setrecursionlimit(10 ** 4)` at the beginning of my code.
But now, when I run my program, it crashes with the message :

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

What is this error and how do I solve it? Or is there an other way to avoid Recursion Errors?

Comment: A recursion depth of 10 ** 4 seems to be quite big. Do you expect this depth? If yes, you might have to find a different solution.

Comment: The 0xC00000FD error is stack overflow. This is what the default recursion limit protects from. Can you share more information about your code?

Comment: Really, the only way to solve this is to not use recursion, especially recursion that results in a linear recursion tree. While there are methods to mechanically convert any kind of recursion into stack-safe code (tail-call optimization, trampolines, etc), Python does not implement any of them.